# how to recover files window form files in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'd created a form in Visual Studio 2010. Somehow my computer was restarted. After restart I cannot open the form. It shows me the icon as C# file but when I double-click the file, it opens in Notepad and displays blank in Notepad. It also gives me the error: `No suitable editor to open the file.`

Please help me recover the file. I have spent lots of time to make this form work.

Comment: Please learn about git, or any other source code management tools. That can help you in this case in the long term if you check in often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under Tools – Options – Environment, you’ll find the AutoRecover page

[image: Auto Recovery Page]

Note that you can opt-out of the AutoRecover feature by unchecking Save AutoRecover information.  I’m very curious if anyone has opted out here, and why.

The rest of the page is self-explanatory, but did you know where VS saves these auto-recovered files?  They are saved in *\…\My Documents\Visual Studio \Backup Files\* .

[image: Auto Recovery Directory]

In case you (hopefully) have never seen the AutoRecover dialog, here’s what it looks like.  It’ll pop up the next time you launch VS.  You have the options to either use the backup file or ignore it.

[image: Auto Recovery Startup]

Comment: Windows 10 Update Policy (-1), Ahmed's reminder of this feature (+1)